# Office 365 Outlook Encrypt not functioning

Tags: outlook, office365

I want to encrypt my email to prevent email forwarding. I try to enable **Options > Encrypt > Connect to Rights Management Servers and get templates**. But it is not functioning. No wait cursor, no any error message. And the email sent out still can be forwarded.
[image]

Anybody have same problem? Any idea?
BTW, I'm using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus desktop version on windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working after few days later I check it again. Perhaps it is because of system restart. Don't know why. Anyway it works now.
[image]